# How to connect to the correct region or endpoint?

Tags: nvm, ibm-cloud-storage

After downloading npm using cmd on pc, I Submit a training run to WML using the cacli train and I got thru the authentication for in order to connect to cloud storage. The problem is when I get to entering the region `(us-geo)` no of the endpoint provided on IBM cloud website works. Keep in mind I'm from Canada, Ottawa. Does anyone have a solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the public endpoint corresponding to your bucket location if running from a machine outside the IBM Cloud compute.
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/basics/endpoints.html#select-regions-and-endpoints

If your bucket is in US Cross Region the public endpoint is
s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud